# Problem with printf by using %s for a char array variable. Get warning message

Tags: c

Hi I'm writing a big project and have some problems. Thanks a lot for helping.

```
project.c: In function ‘Check_Line’:
project.c:484:26: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’,
but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[81]’ [-Wformat=]
        printf("error in %s\n", StrLine);
```

```
    Line_Struct *temp_line = line_head;
    char Line[LineSize], *space = " ", *point = ",", *word = NULL,*Nword;
    char BinaryNumber1[Array_Size] = { "000000000000000" };
    char BinaryNumber2[Array_Size] = { "???????????????" };
    char BinaryNumber3[Array_Size] = { "000000000000000" };
    char StrLine[3][LineSize] = { "null", "null", "null" }; /*Whats the problem here? How should I write it right*/
    int i = 0, A = 12, R = 13, E = 14, num1;
...
...
if ( i > 1){
printf("this operand( %s ) have error argument -take no argument,check if you have space-\n", StrLine[0]);
}
```

Comment: `printf("error in %s\n", StrLine);` `Strline` is an array of 3 strings. Which one do you want to print?

Comment: Thanks for answering. The first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first one

Then choose the first string to print.

```
printf("error in %s\n", StrLine[0]);
```